# User Assigned Managed Identity with service bus from local machine

Tags: c#, azure, authorization, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity

I've been trying to set up to be able to use managed identity to authorize and be able to send messages from my azure function project both locally and when the application is deployed to Azure.

What I've done so far is:

1. Created an managed Identity in Azure:

[image]

2. Associated my Function App Namespace to the managed Identity, as well as the contributor developer group my work account is assigned to. I have also role assigned the service bus I want to use to the managed identity resource. In regards to the role assignment I have tried multiple roles (more on that below):

**Associated Function App:**
[image]

**Assigned Group in Managed Identity:**
[image]

**Role Assigned managed Identity to Servicebus resource:**
[image]

*Note: I have tried 3 roles as you can see: "Azure Servicebus Data Sender", "Azure Servicebus Data Owner" and "Owner".*

3. I have implemented the authorizations parts into the code in my application:

My Servicebus Related Code:

Startup.cs:

```cs
    services.AddSingleton<IServiceBusDataFactory>(new ServiceBusDataFactory("testJohnSb.servicebus.windows.net", new DefaultAzureCredential()));
```

Class:

```cs
        public class ServiceBusDataFactory : IAsyncDisposable, IServiceBusDataFactory
        {
            private readonly ServiceBusClient _client;
            private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusSender> _senders = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusSender>();
            private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusReceiver> _receivers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusReceiver>();
    
            public ServiceBusDataFactory(string fullyQualifiedNamespace, TokenCredential credential) => _client = new ServiceBusClient(fullyQualifiedNamespace, credential);
            public ServiceBusDataFactory(string connectionString) => _client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
    
    
            public ServiceBusSender GetSender(string entity) =>
                _senders.GetOrAdd(entity, entity => _client.CreateSender(entity));
    
            public ServiceBusReceiver GetReceiver(string entity) =>
                _receivers.GetOrAdd(entity, entity => _client.CreateReceiver(entity));
    
            public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
            {
                await _client.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        }
```

But when I trying the workflow I get:

> Unauthorized access. 'Send' claim(s) are required to perform this
> operation. Resource: 'sb://testJohnSb.servicebus.windows.net/zzzqueue'.

Have I missed something?

**EIDT**

After some testing around this is what i found:

*(NOTE: If somebody disagrees with the information below please let me know and i'll correct it.)*

Short version:
Using "User assigned Managed Identity" to **both** authenticate from a deployed/published state in Azure and to be able to use it locally does not work using only a "User Assigned Managed Identitet" role assigned to (in this case) a service bus to be able to send messages to.

This is what i have tried:

With the same setup as above and as mentioned in the comment section of @juunas answer.

1. First, I role assigned only the "User assigned Managed Identity" to the servicebus as a "Azure Servicebus Data Sender".
   **Resulted in:** My Function App being able to send messages published in azure, but not with the same code from visual studio locally.
2. Second, role assigned my work account as a contributer, that I'm logged in as in Visual studio locally, to the "User assigned Managed Identity"-Resource, thinking it would somehow "delegate the permissions" (if that's the right way to put it) and authorize me to be able to send messages to the servicebus using the managed identity that already has ben role assigned "Azure Servicebus Data Sender" in the servicebus.
   **Resulted in:** My Function App still being able to send messages published in azure, and still not with the same code from visual studio locally.
3. Third, I lastly role assigned my work account as a "Azure Servicebus Data Sender", just as I've previously done with the managed identity, to the servicebus.
   **Resulted in:** Both my Function App and my identical local function app project being able to send messages to the servicebus.

If anyone has had any luck getting it to work locally, please write. If I've misunderstood something, wright even then explaining what I've gotten wrong and I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultAzureCredential` will by default only attempt to use a *system-assigned* managed identity, not a user-assigned managed identity.
You can however specify the user-assigned identity client ID to it:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IServiceBusDataFactory>(
  new ServiceBusDataFactory(
    "testJohnSb.servicebus.windows.net",
    new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
    {
      ManagedIdentityClientId = "your-identity-client-id"
    })));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, just tried that exact snippet of code and i still get the same error unfortunately..

Comment: Hmm.. could you try using `ManagedIdentityCredential` directly instead? You should be able to specify the client ID to it as well.

Comment: Nope exactly the same error, this is what i tried now:

services.AddSingleton<IServiceBusDataFactory>(
                new ServiceBusDataFactory(
                    "testJohnSb.servicebus.windows.net",
                    new ManagedIdentityCredential("[ID]")));

The [ID] being my clientID.